# Unable to open messaging channel in Substrate Tutorial

Tags: substrate-parachain-template

1. `chain-spec.rs`
   In [Open Message Passing Channels](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/open-message-passing-channels/) guide, use the [parachain-template.js](https://docs.substrate.io/assets/tutorials/relay-chain-specs/parachain-template-1001.rs/) parachain_id of 1000, 1001 respectively.
2. Add sudo pallet to `runtime/lib.js`.

```
impl pallet_sudo::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
}

construct_time!(
....
// Sudo: pallet_sudo, // or next line does not success open channel
Sudo: pallet_sudo::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Config<T>, Event<T>},
....
)
```

3. Use `cargo build -release` for `node/src/chain-spec.rs` with parachian_id = 1000 and 1001 respectively.
4. Start a test network with zombienet, where config.toml is configured according to the [Simulate Parachains documentation](https://docs.substrate.io/test/simulate-parachains/).

```
[relaychain]
default_command = "polkadot-v0.9.32"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true
  ws_port = 9900


  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true
  ws_port = 9901

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "charlie"
  validator = true
  ws_port = 9902

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "dave"
  validator = true
  ws_port = 9903

[[parachains]]
id = 1000
cumulus_based = true

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "parachain-A-1000-collator01"
  command = "parachain-A-template-node-v0.9.32"
  ws_port = 9910

[[parachains]]
id = 1001
cumulus_based = true

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "parachain-B-1001-collator01"
  command = "parachain-B-template-node-v0.9.32"
  ws_port = 9920

[[hrmpChannels]]
sender = 1000
recipient = 1001
maxCapacity = 8
maxMessageSize = 8000

[[hrmpChannels]]
sender = 1001
recipient = 1000
maxCapacity = 8
maxMessageSize = 8000
```

5. The question arises.
   When I follow the documentation step by step, there is no `hrmp.OpenChannelRequested` event in the recent time of the relay chain when the transaction is submitted, and `ump.ExecutedUpward` shows incomplete.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The extrinsic didn't show an error? Your ump.ExecutedUpward event shows  an error: FailedToTransactAssets

Answer (score 0):

Error: Failed to Transact asset means that you don't have balance in your sovereign account of the particular parachain in the relay chain.